# Explain this answer for differentiating an exponent

Tags: derivatives, exponential-function, implicit-differentiation

Here is the question and answer - [eX](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oe7Q4.png) What confuses me is how $$\frac{2t}{2e^{2t}}=te^{-2t}$$ What I get  is $$\frac{t}{e^{2t}}$$

Comment: In general $a^{-x}=\frac1{a^x}$. Take a look at [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple [exponential properties](http://www.efunda.com/math/exp_log/exp_relation.cfm), by definition

> $$a^{-b} = \frac{1}{a^b}$$